# When console.log passed as a parameter it works, but when array.push is passed a parameter it doesn't work why?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions, array-push

I may be asking a silly question.but I am a beginner.

I saw this example in eloquent JavaScript in the chapter about higher order function.

There is a repeat function that takes 2 arguments.
    1. number of time we want the repetition 
    2. action that we want to repeat

When console.log is passed as 2<sup>nd</sup> argument code works just fine. it produces perfect output.

but when array.push is passed as 2<sup>nd</sup> argument code throws an error, we are required to pass a function as 2<sup>nd</sup> argument to make array.push work.

Please help understanding this concept.

```
//code here works...
function repeat(n, action) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);
  }
}

repeat(3, console.log);

//so why code below does not work...?
function repeat(n, action) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      action(i);
    }
  }

let labels = [];
repeat(5, labels.push);

console.log(labels);

/*
In my understanding labels.push is also a function just like console.log, so it should push i 5 times(i.e 0-4) into labels array.
Please help me where am I wrong.
*/

//Why we require to pass a function as described below.
function repeat(n, action) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      action(i);
    }
  }

let labels = [];
repeat(5, i => labels.push(i));
console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because labels.push requires a context.

if you do `repeat(5, labels.push.bind(labels))`, you will see that it works.

i leave it to you read up on what fn.call(), fn.bind() and fn.apply() do.

Comment: okay, I am sorry if I am being stupid but it will be really helpful if you can elaborate around your first line.
what does it mean that labels.push requires a context, and why console.log does not require that.

Comment: push is an instance method that is attached to an object. if you look into its internal implementation, it calls `this`. and since repeat doesnt have the right context / scope, it is unable to find the labels array you define in the first place. in the case of console.log, it is a function that requires no context. take a look at this to understand `this` better :) https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md#this-identifier

Answer (score 0):

Doing `repeat(5, labels.push.bind(labels))` works, but is pretty awful to read.  Use your arrow function `i => labels.push(i)` instead, because it's **much** easier to read.

`console.log` is globally scoped, so function can access it. `labels.push` is out of `repeat`'s scope, so `repeat` is unable to access it. [This page](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) is very useful if you're trying to understand how arrow functions work